# How can I create a data frame in R from a zip file with multiple levels located in an URL?

Tags: r, zip

I have been trying to work this out but I have not been able to do it...

I want to create a data frame with four columns: country-number-year-(content of the .txt file)

There is a .zip file in the following URL:
https://dataverse.harvard.edu/api/access/datafile/:persistentId?persistentId=doi:10.7910/DVN/0TJX8Y/PZUURT

The file contains a folder with 49 folders in it, and each of them contain 150 .txt files give or take.

I first tried to download the zip file with get_dataset but did not work

```
if (!require("dataverse")) devtools::install_github("iqss/dataverse-client-r")
library("dataverse")
Sys.setenv("DATAVERSE_SERVER" = "dataverse.harvard.edu")
get_dataset("=doi:10.7910/DVN/0TJX8Y/PZUURT", key = "", server = "dataverse.harvard.edu")
```

"Error in get_dataset("=doi:10.7910/DVN/0TJX8Y/PZUURT", key = "", server = "dataverse.harvard.edu") : 
  Not Found (HTTP 404)."

Then I tried

```
temp <- tempfile()
download.file("https://dataverse.harvard.edu/api/access/datafile/:persistentId?persistentId=doi:10.7910/DVN/0TJX8Y/PZUURT",temp)
UNGDC <-unzip(temp, "UNGDC+1970-2018.zip")
```

It worked to some point... I downloaded the .zip file and then I created UNGDC but nothing happened, because it only has the following information:

> UNGDC
>   A connection with
>   description "/var/folders/nl/ss_qsy090l78_tyycy03x0yh0000gn/T//RtmpTc3lvX/fileab730f392b3:UNGDC+1970-2018.zip"
>   class       "unz"
>   mode        "r"
>   text        "text"
>   opened      "closed"
>   can read    "yes"
>   can write   "yes"

Here I don't know what to do... I have not found relevant information to proceed... Can someone please give me some hints? or any web to learn how to do it?

Thanks for your attention and help!!!

Comment: Once unzip file you have the data folder on your disk. You can use `list.dirs` & `list.files` to view the content of the folder and process it base on the values returned with a loop.

Comment: The downloaded file does not appear to be a zip archive? At any rate, I'm unable to unzip using either Windows' uncompress or 7-Zip.

Comment: @SinhNguyen I know that I can download it to my hard drive, and then start to merge folder by folder, but there should be a way to do it through the URL and just using code.

Comment: @user2474226 this is the webpage that contains the link I shared: https://dataverse.harvard.edu/file.xhtml?persistentId=doi:10.7910/DVN/0TJX8Y/PZUURT&version=5.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this? I used the zip package to unzip, but possibly the base unzip might work as well.

```
library(zip)
dir.create(temp <- tempfile())
url<-'https://dataverse.harvard.edu/api/access/datafile/:persistentId?persistentId=doi:10.7910/DVN/0TJX8Y/PZUURT'
download.file(url, paste0(temp, '/PZUURT.zip'), mode = 'wb', exdir = temp)
unzip(paste0(temp, '/PZUURT.zip'), exdir = temp)
```

Note in particular I had to set the mode = 'wb' as I'm on a Windows machine.

I then saw that the unzipped archive had a _MACOSX folder and a Converted sessions folder. Assuming I don't need the MACOSX stuff, I did the following to get just the files I'm interested in:

```
root_folder <- paste0(temp,'/Converted sessions/')
filelist <- list.files(path = root_folder, pattern = '*.txt', recursive = TRUE)
filenames <- basename(filelist)
```

'filelist' contains the full paths to each text file, while 'filenames' has just each file name, which I'll then break up to get the country, the number and the year:

```
df <- data.frame(t(sapply(strsplit(filenames, '_'), 
                 function(x) c(x[1], x[2], substr(x[3], 1, 4)))))
colnames(df) <- c('Country', 'Number', 'Year')
```

Finally, I can read the text from each of the files and stick it into the dataframe as a new Text field:

```
df$Text <- sapply(paste0(root_folder, filelist), function(x) readChar(x, file.info(x)$size))
```

Comment: Thank you very much @user2474226 !!!! It totally solved my struggle!!!